# Remove Duplicate ID's?

Tags: php, algorithm, file, file-io, duplicates

I have a list of 50,000 ID's in a flat file and need to remove any duplicate ID's. Is there any efficient/recommended algorithm for my problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Probably not the fastest solution, but I remembered about array_unique. Put them all into an array (1 id per element), use array_unique and write them back to the file. Anything against doing this?

Comment: are they separated by line breaks? ( \n ) ?

Comment: Yes they are separated by line breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've did some experiments once and the fastest solution I could get in PHP was by sorting the items and manually remove all the duplicate items.

If performance isn't that much of an issue for you (which I suspect, 50,000 is not that much) than you can use `array_unique()`: http://php.net/array_unique

Comment: I ran this and it completed it in about a second. I thought it would take longer. Thanks.

Comment: @Jamie: The IO will probably dwarf the processing, because generating a unique set will have a max algorithmic complexity of n log n, which is somewhat fast, and most disk IO is very slow.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the command line `sort` program to order and filter the list of ids.  This is a very efficient program and scales well too.

```
sort -u ids.txt > filteredIds.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Read into a dictionary line by line, discarding duplicates. When all read, write out to a new file.

Answer (score 0):

i guess if you have large enough memory allowance, you can put all these ids in array

```
$array[$id] = $id;
```

this would automatically weed out the dupes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
file_put_contents($file,implode("\n",array_unique(file($file)));
```

How it works?

- Read the file using function `file`
  which returns an array.
- Get rid of the duplicate lines using
  `array_unique`
- implode those unique lines with "\n"
  to get a string
- write the string back to the file
  using `file_put_contents`

This solution assumes that you've got one ID per line in the flat file.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a terminal (or native unix execution), the easiest way: (assuming that there is nothing else in the file):

`sort < ids.txt | uniq > filteredIds.txt`

Comment: uniq will only work if the ids are consecutive and duplicates are next to each other.

Comment: Good point; I thought uniq auto-sorted:`sort < ids.txt | uniq > filteredIDS.txt`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via array / array_unique, in this example i guess your ids are separated by line braks, if thats not the case just change it

```
$file = file_get_contents('/path/to/file.txt');
$array = explode("\n",$file);
$array = array_unique($array);
$file = implode("\n",$array);
file_put_contents('/path/to/file.txt',$file);
```

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer. I selected an answer before I seen this one.

Comment: @Jamie Redmond don't sweat it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can just explode the contents of the file on a comma (or any delimiter), then array_unique will produce the least (and cleanest) code, otherwise if your are parsing the file going with the $array[$id] = $id is the fastest and cleanest solution.